# Swift: How to use optional in ternary check for disabling button

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-optionals

I have a simple task for JS, and I have no idea how to make it using Swift. Help me please to understand and make this.

I need just check if state value is or not `nil`, and disable the button.

```
Button(action: {onBoardingNav.goTo(step: 3)} ) {...}
    .disabled($selectedLanguage != nil)

// Error: Type 'Binding<UUID?>' is not optional, value can never be nil
```

Comment: It should be `.disabled(selectedLanguage != nil)` without the $ sign and of course selectedLanguage needs to be declared as an optional variable, `@State private var selectedLanguage: UUID?`

Answer (score 1):

If `.disabled(selectedLanguage != nil)` did not work (notice no `$`), then try `.disabled($selectedLanguage.wrappedValue != nil)`